# Can you have interaction terms between two categorical variables in linear regression?

Tags: r, regression

I have the variables day and month, and convert them to factors to predict the temperature. Would it make sense to have an interaction term between these two? I'm not really sure what the interpretation would be.

```
day <- as.factor(day)
month<- as.factor(month)
lm.fit <- lm(temp~day*month)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes!**

Regarding interpretation, if you have a significant$^{\dagger}$ Friday:May effect, it means that Fridays in May are different from the other days. If only Fridays in May are significant, it means that all of the days are about the same, except for Fridays in May.

If only Friday is significant, it means that Fridays are different from the other six days, but not just in May. If only May is significant, it means that the days in May are different from the days in the other month, but this effect is across the entire month, not specific to a particular day of the week.

Ditto for the other days and months...

$^{\dagger}$Whatever "significant" means...